# Hide JSP url extension

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, struts

How can I change the following JSP:

```
http://localhost/test/user/people/something.do?method=delete
```

to this:

```
http://localhost/test/user/people/
```

?

Answer (score 1):

You need to take a look at URL rewriting. There are two popular solutions.

1. Apache based [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html)
2. Servlet filter based [UrlRewriteFilter](http://www.tuckey.org/urlrewrite/)

You can expose a URL such as `http://www.example.com/test/user/profile/delete` and have it re-written internally in to `http://www.example.com/test/user/profile`/something.do?method=delete.